# How to save/load files from File Manager in background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, persistence, grand-central-dispatch, file-manager

I am using File manger to save a simple JSON file. The issue is I want to do this asynchronously and on the background thread. So far I am having issues getting this accomplished. I am adding a code sample below and would welcome some help! Thanks!

```
init(apiService: apiService) {
    self.updateAction = Action(apiService.revision)
    self.updateAction.values.observeValues { [weak self] revisionDataContainer in
        guard let data = revisionDataContainer.data, let this = self else {
            return
        }
        do {
            try this.save(data: data, to: this.currentRevisionUrl)
            this.currentRevision.value = try this.parse(data: data) as Revision
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: self.currentRevisionUrl.path) {
            self.currentRevision.value = try self.load(from: self.currentRevisionUrl) as Revision
        } else {
            self.currentRevision.value = try self.load(from: self.seedRevisionUrl) as Revision
        }
    } catch let error {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to this on a background thread? What is `apiService`? FYI - class names should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I deleted it from here because I was a bit lost. But it was in the firs `do` block since this is where I parse the data

Comment: Also apiService is where I make a request to the network

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run this code in background thread, then you need to create a new instance of `FileManager` instead of using `default`.

> This method always represents the same file manager object. If you
> plan to use a delegate with the file manager to receive notifications
> about the completion of file-based operations, you should create a new
> instance of FileManager (using the init method) rather than using the
> shared object.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1409234-default